# Child from Parent Generic class

Tags: ios, swift, polymorphism

I have a Parent Class

```
 class Parent<T: Codable>: Codable, Hashable {
    let data: T
    let property1: String
 }
```

and I want to extend this functionality with few more properties

```
class Child: Parent {
    let property2: String
}
```

How to do that correctly ?
Receiving errors like "Reference to generic type 'Parent' requires arguments in <...>"

And then "Expected '>' to complete generic argument list"

Comment: Parent is declared as generic so you need to treat it as a generic when sub-classing, you can't hide this part of the declaration. So something like `class Child: Parent<String>`

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
class Parent<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let data1: T
    let property1: String
}

class Child<T: Codable>: Parent<T> {
    let property2: String
}
```